# BLE - Connect Android phones that support only central mode

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to connect over BLE two Android phones that only support Central mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect two centrals with each other. One must be central and one must be peripheral. Or more correctly, one must be master and one must be slave.